# Unable to find plugin in intellij idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, sonarqube

I'm trying out Sonar `(@http://localhost:9000)` for scanning my source code and reporting issues. In order to achieve that, I created a sample maven project in Intellij Idea and added the following in the pom.xml

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.6.0.1398</version>
</plugin>
```

When I clean/install/run the project, build is successful. But I'm unable to view the sonar plugin under the Maven projects tab. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Did you try to install it from the plugin manager, instead?

Comment: is it working fine